# Popup Shall Appear When User Scroll About 10% of Page

Tags: javascript, html, blogs

Hi Can Somebody Help me Out Here  I want this popup window to appear after the user scrolls in the page heres my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var adblock = true;
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="adframe.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 if(adblock) 
 {
 alert("We Noticed You are using Ad blocker :( We Work Really Hard and Spend Huge Time to test 
 and verify these files for you. Please Support us By Disabling Ad blocker for this Domain. We 
 dont show any popups or Poor Ads. Because we hate them too. If you cannot disable Ad blocker 
 for our site. We can understand, Dont Worry! Your Download will start always regardless of Ad 
 Blocker. Consider sending us small donation. Because we want to keep this site free as long 
 as possible.");
 document.getElementById("wrapper").style.display="none";
 }
</script>
```

so can somebody help this script to modify and make this to appear like when user scrolls the page it shall appear

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely different things.

Answer (score 3):

This will get the job done!

```
let ScrollThreshold = window.innerHeight/10; //Divide the full height of window by 10 to get your 10%

document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) 
{
  if(window.scrollY > ScrollThreshold)
  {
   //Add your pop-up code right here!
    console.log(`The window scroll is at ${window.scrollY}, which is beyond the threshold of ${ScrollThreshold}`);  
  }
  
});
```

Comment: this is not working i did tried like this is this correct im trying or wrong 

let ScrollThreshold = window.innerHeight/10; //Divide the full height of window by 10 to get your 10%

document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) 
{
  if(window.scrollY > ScrollThreshold)
  {
    <script type="text/javascript">
 var adblock = true;
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="adframe.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 if(adblock)
    console.log(`The window scroll is at ${window.scrollY}, which is beyond the threshold of ${ScrollThreshold}`);  
  }
  
});

Comment: @ThizisSam The code i provided above should reside inside a javascript file so there will be no need to add any <script> tags... that will just produce errors. Okay, so let me give you a little debugging advice to get this to work. [1] Create a function in your javascript file called something like 'Check_Adblock()'  [2] in that function, place all code responsible for checking and triggering the alert. Test that code by calling the function in the browser's console. [3] Once your function is tested and is working, paste the function  'Check_Adblock()' right where it says "Add your code here"